# phpMyAdmin Erro "Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image: Erro 1]

[image: Erro 2]

[image: Erro 3]

error_log

```
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:42.851072 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1851] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:43.036199 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1852] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:43.133545 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1852] AH00163: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:43.133637 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1852] AH00094: Command line: '/home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:46.076120 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1852] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:48.794010 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1884] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:48.891244 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1885] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:48.925044 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1885] AH00163: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 05 16:58:48.925091 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1885] AH00094: Command line: '/home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Jun 05 17:07:36.331831 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1885] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jun 05 17:07:50.569985 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2249] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 17:07:50.682066 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2250] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/lab/lampstack-7/php/lib/php/extensions/php_imap.dll' - /home/lab/lampstack-7/php/lib/php/extensions/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 05 17:07:50.752903 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2250] AH00163: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 05 17:07:50.753014 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2250] AH00094: Command line: '/home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:08.673105 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 2275] [client 191.54.90.184:58315] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/, referer: http://107.170.5.121:8080/applications.html
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:16.489892 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2250] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:20.692296 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2298] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:20.798845 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 2299] AH01909: localhost:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/lab/lampstack-7/php/lib/php/extensions/php_imap.dll' - /home/lab/lampstack-7/php/lib/php/extensions/php_imap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:20.845833 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2299] AH00163: Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:20.845913 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2299] AH00094: Command line: '/home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/bin/httpd.bin -f /home/lab/lampstack-7/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:24.912022 2016] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 2305] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @2305] CSS parsing error in http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/js/whitelist.php?lang=pt_BR&db=&token=262c93025c45e3676dfcf1d33e7a9023&v=4.6.1
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:25.562332 2016] [:error] [pid 2302] [client 191.54.90.184:58323] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare PMA_sprites() (previously declared in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php:22) in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php on line 22, referer: http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:30.926531 2016] [:error] [pid 2323] [client 191.54.90.184:58331] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare PMA_sprites() (previously declared in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php:22) in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php on line 22, referer: http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:32.661753 2016] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 2324] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @2324] CSS parsing error in http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:35.110113 2016] [:error] [pid 2301] [client 191.54.90.184:58335] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare PMA_sprites() (previously declared in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php:22) in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php on line 22, referer: http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/
[Sun Jun 05 17:09:38.602758 2016] [:error] [pid 2302] [client 191.54.90.184:58336] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare PMA_sprites() (previously declared in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php:22) in /home/lab/lampstack-7/apps/phpmyadmin/htdocs/themes/pmahomme/sprites.lib.php on line 22, referer: http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/
[Sun Jun 05 17:11:02.668256 2016] [pagespeed:warn] [pid 2328] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.14-0 @2328] CSS parsing error in http://107.170.5.121:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

Querem que poste o php.ini e o http.conf

Estou usando um servidor Debian com o Bitnami Lampstack-7.0.7-Dev

Comment: Tente limpar a cache de seu browser e apagar as cookies

Comment: já tentei nao funciona